# How to use token based authentication in node.js

Tags: node.js, arduino, esp8266

my scenario is that I have an esp8266 which is sending some sensor data to a node server. Basically I just have a post request API which is configured on the server.

The ESP 8266 connects to wifi and starts sending data to the server, my question is:

1. Should each of my ESP 8266 be configured as users on the server and login for posting their data?
2. Is there another way I should be doing this like using a token based authentication which will allow the device to post their data while at the same time keeping my API secure? If so what should be my approach?

Thanks in advance